# How to disable IPv6 on windows server 2019

Tags: ipv6, windows-server-2019

I need to disable IPv6 on my machine as it wont work otherwise but when I go to it says I don't have permission when I am administrator! Please help. Im using virtual box for the server.

Comment: You should absolutely have permissions to disable your IPv6 compatibility for your network adapter, however, if for some reason you don’t what you want cannot be achieved.  **It sounds like you are not an Administrator.**

Comment: You should not have to disable IPv6 and it is not a good idea. Sometimes disabling IPv6 can cause issues. Find out what has happened / been installed to make you do this